# Control-drag to AppDelegate only

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

Xcode 6.1, OSX not ios, allows me to  Control-drag  from a button in MainMenu.xib to AppDelegate only. This is unfortunate for me because my IBAction must include view methods like [self setNeedsDisplay:YES] . I need to Control-drag it into my MyView file, which will tolerate them. This also makes more sense.

Control-dragging from the button to any file other than AppDelegate does nothing.

Identity Inspector > Class is set to MYView.

How can I make this work, and how does the fix work? 
Also, why is it now restricted to AppDelegate? Perhaps a timing issue?

Thanks ahead,

Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try dragging an empty object from the object library to the area where you see 'AppDelegate' then selecting it and setting its' class to 'MyView' then secondary dragging to that object to create the IBAction.

Comment: thanks, this makes the button action work. Unfortunately, it introduces a new problem: ivar integers that were initialized in initWithCoder are set to zero. I don't know if this connection is the cause of it. I have never seen this in past projects.

Comment: Got the same problem. It worked. Searched two days. THANKS so much!

Comment: This is actually something I have to do often, so don't forget that you can do this! And @j yrez, I'm so sorry but I have no idea what initWithCoder even is. I can't help you with that. I'm actually a noob tbh.